# Lazy loading of optionally dependent properties throws resolution exception

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, unity-container

I'm using Unity to make sure my application is loosely coupled.

I need to use lazy-loading of an optional property on one of my classes. I've marked  this property with an `[OptionalDependency]` attribute.

When the property has indeed been registered with Unity my code works fine, and I can get the value from the property. I'd expect the property to contain `null` if the property HASN'T been registered (as far as I know using `OptionalDependency` causes Unity to suppress its own exception)... but that's not the case. I get a typical Unity exception about it failing to resolve an interface type.

Am I seeing it right that `OptionalDependency` doesn't work with `Lazy`, or am I missing something (either with Unity or Lazy classes)?

Here's the code sample I'm currently working on:

```
    [OptionalDependency]
    public Lazy<IEventCollection<T>> EventCollection { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IEvent<T>> Events
    {
        get
        {
            if (EventCollection != null && EventCollection.Value != null)  //Exception thrown on this line
                return EventCollection.Value.Events;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

The exact exception is as follows:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "IEventCollection`1[ComponentType]", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, IEventCollection`1[ComponentType], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

-----------------------------------------------

At the time of the exception, the container was:



  Resolving IEventCollection`1[ComponentType],(none)
```

Like I wrote - this is the standard exception Unity throws when attempting to resolve an interface mapping which hasn't been registered. Again - my understanding is that `[OptionalDependency]` should handle this exact case.

Comment: what is the actual exception?

Comment: @tdbeckett I've added the exception to the question.

Comment: i think the problem is that `IEventCollection` is an interface, you can't create an instance of it. Do you have a mapping from `IEventCollection` to an instantiatable class? I don't see why you would want to make this lazy, I assume your `EventCollection` is a light weight class?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys No, but this is exactly WHY I'm using an `OptionalDependency` attribute! The code comes from a base class which can be reused and the mapping will be created only in specific cases. In others (where only a basic implementation of my class is used) it WILL be missing. To my knowledge `[OptionalDependency]` should handle this case and just return null... As for why it's `Lazy` - this prevents a circular dependency resolution problem inside Unity; the `IEventCollection` can contain classes which need Unity to resolve properties which may or may not require the current class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Unity (at least version 3.5.1404.0) indeed has issues with `[OptionalDependency]` and `Lazy`.

Consider the following example:

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Operation();
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        [OptionalDependency]
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }

        public void Operation()
        {
            if (Bar == null)
                Console.Write("Bar is null..");
            else
                Console.Write("Bar isn't null!");
        }
    }

    (...)

    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(); //container is an IUnityContainer
    var fooInstance = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
    fooInstance.Operation();
```

The above code will function as expected - calling the test operation without registering `Bar` will result in *Bar is null..* written to the console.

However, after a slight chance to the code (change `public Bar` into `public Lazy<Bar>` and change `Bar == null` into `Bar == null || Bar.Value == null`) calling `Bar.Value` throws a Unity exception.

The only way around that is to manually put a try-catch block around `Bar.Value`.